# HTML file can't find embedded js files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm currently trying to make a game using Node.js, Express, and Socket.io. However, when I attempt to run it locally I get a 404 error stating that my javascript files can't be found. My file structure looks like this:

```
root
| game
| | game.html
| | game.js
| index.js
```

And my code looks like this:

index.js

```
//Dependencies
var express = require('express'); //Pulls in Express framework
var http = require('http') //Pulls in http module
var socketio = require('socket.io'); //Pulls in Socket.io framework

//Instance Declarations
var app = express(); //Creates an Express instance
var server = http.createServer(app); //Creates an http server using the Express framework
var port_to_listen = process.env.PORT || 3000; //Specifies which port to listen on
var socket = socketio(http); //Creates Socket.io instance related to the server just created

//Default page displayed, always sent to index.html
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/game/game.html');
});

//Tells the server to listen for any incoming inconnections
server.listen(port_to_listen, () => {
  console.log(`listening on ${port_to_listen}`);
});

socket.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Connection made')
});

//Testing to ensure socketio works
setInterval(function() {
  socket.sockets.emit('message', 'hi!');
}, 1000);
```

game.js

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('message', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

game.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Multiplayer Game</title>
    <style>
      canvas {
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
        border: 5px solid black;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</html>
```

The error messages look like this:

[image: error]

What should I do to fix these errors?

Edit:
These errors also still persist when I change the src path for game.js to

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="/game/game.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only one route that serves files:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/game/game.html');
});
```

The rest of the files (your css, js, etc.)  **are not served automatically**

You need to create route(s) for that, like explained here [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: I tried adding "app.use(express.static( 'game'));" but that failed to resolve any errors

Comment: Nevermind. I needed to create a virtual path prefix in order for it to work.

Comment: Yeah, a common gotcha with the prefix :)